# PrimeNG Dropdown - How to set two value in one optionLabel

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

I want to set two values in one label. As an example, if I open the dropdown, it should show as:

> "value1 value2"

in one line with space. `value1` and `value2` data are getting from the database. I tried using the below method but it has not worked.

```
<p-dropdown [options]="divitionArr" name="business_divition" [(ngModel)]="project.business_divition" optionLabel="{'first_name','last_name'}" optionValue="divition" #diviSel="ngModel"></p-dropdown>
```

Answer (score 7):

Would suggest that add a new field, `displayLabel`  into the element of the array that is used for the `optionLabel`. And next, you decide the desired output for `displayLabel`.

> .component.ts

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.divitionArr = this.divitionArr.map((divition: any) => {
    return {
      ...divition,
      displayLabel: divition.first_name + ' ' + divition.last_name
    };
  });
}
```

> .component.html

```
<p-dropdown
  [options]="divitionArr"
  name="business_divition"
  [(ngModel)]="project.business_divition"
  optionLabel="displayLabel"
  optionValue="divition"
  #diviSel="ngModel"
>
</p-dropdown>
```

[Sample Demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dybg3o?)

Answer (score 4):

Try using the `<ng-template>` like this:

```
<label for="operatingSystem">Operating System</label>
<p-dropdown id="operatingSystem" [options]="operatingSystems" [(ngModel)]="application.operatingSystem"
            placeholder="Select an Operating System"  [showClear]="true">
  <ng-template let-operatingSystems pTemplate="item">
    <div class="flex align-items-center operatingSystems-item">
      <div>{{operatingSystems.name}} {{operatingSystems.version}}</div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</p-dropdown>
```